# Is it possible to make select operation without JOIN command by using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: sql, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have three Entities: `User`, `UserFile` and `UserSearchInfo`. User entity has a one-to-one relationship to UserFile entity and one-to-one relationship to UserSearchInfo entity.

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
        @Id
        val id: UUID,
        val username: String?,
        val age: Int,
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val lang: Language?,
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val city: City?,
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val genderType: GenderType,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime,
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime
) {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    val userSearchInfo: UserSearchInfo? = null

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    val userFile: UserFile? = null
}
```

UserFile entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_file")
data class UserFile(
        @Id
        val id: UUID,
        val fileId: String,
        val fileName: String,
        val mimeType: String,
        val fileSize: Int,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime,
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime
) {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    val user: User? = null
}
```

UserSearchInfo entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_search_info")
data class UserSearchInfo(
        @Id
        val id: UUID,
        val ageFrom: Int,
        val ageTo: Int,
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val city: City?,
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val genderType: GenderType,
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime,
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime
) {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    val user: User? = null
}
```

I want to make this SQL operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_file as userFile
ON users.id = userFile.id
JOIN users_search_info as userSearchInfo
ON users.id = userSearchInfo.id
WHERE users.id != :userId AND age >= :ageStart AND age <= :ageEnd
AND users.gender_type = :genderType AND userSearchInfo.gender_type = :wantedGenderType
ORDER BY CASE WHEN lang = :firstLang then '1'
              WHEN lang = :secondLang then '2'
              ELSE lang END,
         userFile ASC NULLS LAST;
```

I did it by using JOIN command:

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, UUID> {
    @Query("""
        SELECT user
        FROM User user
        LEFT JOIN UserFile userFile
        ON user.id = userFile.id
        JOIN UserSearchInfo userSearchInfo
        ON user.id = userSearchInfo.id
        WHERE user.id != :userId AND user.age >= :ageStart AND user.age <= :ageEnd
        AND user.genderType = :genderType AND userSearchInfo.genderType = :wantedGenderType
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN user.lang = :firstLang then '1'
                      WHEN user.lang = :secondLang then '2'
                      ELSE user.lang END,
                 userFile ASC NULLS LAST
    """)
    fun findUsers(
            @Param("userId") userId: UUID,
            @Param("firstLang") firstLang: Language,
            @Param("secondLang") secondLang: Language,
            @Param("ageStart") ageStart: Int,
            @Param("ageEnd") ageEnd: Int,
            @Param("genderType") genderType: GenderType,
            @Param("wantedGenderType") wantedGenderType: GenderType
    ): List<User>
}
```

Also, I tried to do without JOIN command. But it doesn't work:

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, UUID> {

    @Query("""
        SELECT user
        FROM User user
        WHERE user.id != :userId AND user.age >= :ageStart AND user.age <= :ageEnd
        AND user.genderType = :genderType AND user.userSearchInfo.genderType = :wantedGenderType
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN user.lang = :firstLang then '1'
                      WHEN user.lang = :secondLang then '2'
                      ELSE user.lang END,
                 user.userFile ASC NULLS LAST
    """)
    fun findUsers(
            @Param("userId") userId: UUID,
            @Param("firstLang") firstLang: Language,
            @Param("secondLang") secondLang: Language,
            @Param("ageStart") ageStart: Int,
            @Param("ageEnd") ageEnd: Int,
            @Param("genderType") genderType: GenderType,
            @Param("wantedGenderType") wantedGenderType: GenderType
    ): List<User>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `left join` or `join` inside query because `JPQL` do this job. in your case try this:

```
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, UUID> {


    @Query("select u,(case  
    when (u.lang = :firstLang) then 1
    when (u.lang = :secondLang) then 2
    else 3 END) as myLang from User as u where u.id=:userId and u.age >= :ageStart and u.age<=:ageEnd and u.genderType=:genderType and u.userSearchInfo.genderType=:wantedGenderType order by myLang,u.userFile asc nulls last")
    fun findUsers @Param("userId") userId: UUID,
        @Param("firstLang") firstLang: Language,
        @Param("secondLang") secondLang: Language,
        @Param("ageStart") ageStart: Int,
        @Param("ageEnd") ageEnd: Int,
        @Param("genderType") genderType: GenderType,
        @Param("wantedGenderType") wantedGenderType: GenderType): List<User>


}
```